# How to check if there is a SSH hostname resolution error

Tags: python, error-handling, subprocess, scp

I'm using Python to automate copying binaries off a network sensor using scp.  I want to add in some error checking and I can't figure out how to reliably check if SSH throws errors, such as a hostname resolution error.  I'm currently using .communicate() to collect stdout, and then matching on "ssh" in the error message.  The reason I'm checking if err starts with "ssh" is because if no error is thrown, that err variable contains the banner of the sensor it's logging in to, so I don't really have a way to reliably check if err actually has a value or not (If that makes sense).  I'm also checking error codes in case a file is not found or some other error is tossed.  Is there a better method?

This is the currently working code:

```
    sp = Popen(['scp', '@'.join([self.user, self.sensor]) + ':{0}{1}'.format(self.binPath, self.binName), self.storePath], stdout = PIPE, stderr = PIPE)
    data, error = sp.communicate()

    if error.startswith("ssh"):
        print("ERROR: {}".format(error))
    else:
        if sp.returncode == 1:
            print("ERROR:  {} - No such file or directory".format(self.binPath + self.binName))
        elif sp.returncode == 0:
            self.hashCMP(self.storePath, self.binName, md5Sum)
        else:
            pass
```

Comment: `sp.returncode == 0` means success, `sp.returncode > 0` means failure regardless of `error` value. Move it outside `else` block

Comment: unrelated: `"{user}@{sensor}:{binPath}{binName}".format(**vars(self))`

Comment: Thanks.  I've noticed that if I have a hostname that SSH can't resolve, it fails outside of the returncode check, which is why I have it parsing `error` instead of just checking the return code.  Also, for your second "unrelated" post, are you suggesting I change my Popen structure to that?

Comment: what does it mean "fail outside of the returncode"? Do you mean `scp` exits with `sp.returncode == 0` and does nothing if `self.sensor` is unknown hostname? On my machine `scp` returns `sp.returncode == 1` in this case. The example with `''.format` shows that it can be done: everything is in one place and the names are readable. Whether to use it is upto you (e.g., `vars(self)` fails for class attributes)

Comment: I got it to work properly thanks to your help.  One note I have is that your suggestion of `"{user}@{sensor}:{binPath}{binName}".format(**vars(self))"` didn't work for me, it kept reporting file or directory not found.  This is the command that worked for me: `Popen(["scp", "{user}@{sensor}:{binPath}{binName}".format(**vars(self)), "{storePath}".format(**vars(self))])`.  I also had to use `.communicate()` to get the `returncode`, otherwise it kept reporting `None` since the process wouldn't terminate.  I tried `.wait()`, but it reported that an int object didnt have the attribute returncode.

Comment: `''.format` can't report "file or directory not found"; it just returns a string. Check its value. Use `self.storePath` instead of `"{storePath}".format(**vars(self))`. `.wait()` already returns exit code (the integer), you shouldn't call `.returncode` on it.

Comment: I'm not saying `''.format` reports "file or directory not found.  What I'm saying is when I used the `''.format` structure you provided it was throwing an OSError saying "file or directory not found".  I know `.wait()` returns an exit code, but I want to determine if the error is a hostname error (i.e. it cant resolve the hostname via DNS) or if its an error with it not finding the file on the host, etc.  That's why I'm parsing the stdout.  IF there is a better way to do it without going through that process I'm all for it, but just a return code of 0 or 1 doesnt give me anything specific

Comment: 1. the format call should return the *same* result as yours `'@'.join + ''.format` expression. Either both should lead to OSError or neither. If they return different result; tell me. 2. *"I tried .wait(), but it reported that an int object didnt have the attribute returncode"* -- returncode and exit code are the same here. If you know `.wait()` returns an exit code; you shouldn't try to get its non-existent `returncode` attribute. 3. Use `if sp.returncode != 0: # parse error` if returncode along doesn't narrow down what specific error might have occurred.

Comment: The format call you suggested was returning an OSError, however, my `'@'.join+''.format` was not. I had it formatted as `Popen(["scp {user}@{sensor}:{binPath}{binName}".format(**vars(self))])` and not `Popen(["scp", "{user}@{sensor}:{binPath}{binName}".format(**vars(self)), self.storePath])'.  The latter works fine, just like my original `'@'.join+''.format` call did.  The former, which is what you suggested caused an OSError for me.  2. I couldn't get the returncode from `.wait()`, it kept reporting that an int object had no attribute returncode. Is there another attribute to check?

Comment: 1. `"scp {user}.."` is wrong and I have not suggested it anywhere. I've suggested the correct `"{user}.."` 2. `rc = sp.wait(); assert rc == sp.returncode` -- I don't know how to make it more clear that it is the same thing

Comment: 1 - I have to add `scp` in there somewhere, I'm using that to copy the file off so it has to be part of the command. 2 - `sp.returncode` when using `wait()` returns the error that an int object does not have the attribute returncode. 3 - Either way the code I have works, thanks for the help.

Comment: you already has `scp` in the command: it is the first item in the list: `['scp', join_or_format_expression_here, other_args..]` 2. calling `sp.wait()` won't make `sp.returncode` disappear unless you are reassigning `sp` by mistake. 3. The purpose of this discussion is to improve *your understanding* of the code.

Comment: I'm following on 1 now, I thought you were suggesting to place it together into a single string.  That explains why that has to be a separate item in the list.  2 - Still not following the issue with returncode.  If I use `wait()` and do a `print sp.returncode` I get the error int object has no attribute returncode.  This is where my issue is.  If I do `sp.communicate()` and do `print sp.returncode` it returns the code, a `0` or `1`.  Im also using `communicate()` so I get more error clarity, such as hostname resolution error instead of just a returncode of 1

Comment: Also, if I use `wait()` and want to pipe to stdout and stderr it seems to deadlock, whereas using `communicate()` doesnt have that issue.

Comment: I guess to make it clearer, this is my new subprocess call: `p = Popen(["scp", "{user}@{sensor}:{binPath}{binName}".format(**vars(self)), self.storePath], stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE).wait()`.  If I do `print p.returncode` I get the error `int object has no attribute returncode`.  This should be the same as testing with `assert`.  If I change my subprocess call to use `communicate()` I can get the return code properly.

Comment: this is incorrect. a) don't use `PIPE` unless you read/write to the pipes by using `.communicate()` or stdin/stdout/stderr objects directly. You are correct that a deadlock is possible if you just use `.wait()` b) **`.wait()` returns an integer**. To call `p.returncode`, you should assign the value of `Popen()` call to it instead: `p = Popen(.., no PIPE here); print(type(p)); rc = p.wait(); assert rc == p.returncode`. If you want to use PIPE (to redirect subprocess std* streams) then use `p = Popen(.., PIPE can be here); output, errors = p.communicate(); print(p.returncode)`

Comment: Ok, I see what you're saying.  So if I use `wait()` without `PIPE` the only error insight I'll have is the exit code, not what the specific error would be correct?  That's the sole reason I was using `PIPE` and `communicate()`, to parse the output to see the specific error not just the return code.  So if I can get more clarity on the error without using `PIPE` I'm all for it, I just couldn't find another method outside of `PIPE` and `communicate()`

Answer (score 0):

Would one way around this be to create a test for the domain? For example using something like:

```
      from socket import getaddrinfo
      result = getaddrinfo("www.google.com", None) 
      print result[0][4]
```

I notice you are using popen - if your OS has nc (netcat) could you maybe run the command:

```
      nc -v <host> <port> #I believe this uses the getaddrinfo under the hood as well ;-)
```

Thanks,
//P